# If I login linux using serial port console, does it using the terminfo or termcap?

Tags: linux, console, termcap, terminfo

linux console implemented by the VT subsystem of the linux kernel, when I login in form the serial port console, does it using the terminfo or termcap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no difference.  A few systems may use a termcap *library* for certain applications (offhand, probably only Slackware), but an application uses the same libraries whether or not it runs on a serial port.

Several applications use a termcap *interface* to the ncurses library (which provides both termcap and terminfo interfaces), but that does not change the answer.  They will still use the same library (and same interface) simply because there's little point in switching between different low-level interfaces to the same library.

By "interface" of course is meant the handful of functions which are used to initialize and query the terminal database.  An application using a termcap *interface* to ncurses still gets terminfo data, albeit slightly adjusted to work better with applications such as `screen` which assume that the alternate character set is *not* reset by the termcap `md` (the "same" as `sgr0`).

Further reading:

- [Types of library users](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library) (ncurses FAQ)
- [**PC, UP, BC, ospeed, tgetent, tgetflag, tgetnum, tgetstr,
  tgoto, tputs** - d*irect curses interface to the terminfo
  capability database*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html)
- [**del_curterm, mvcur, putp, restartterm, set_curterm,
  setterm, setupterm, tigetflag, tigetnum, tigetstr, tiparm,
  tparm, tputs, vid_attr, vid_puts, vidattr, vidputs** -
  *curses interfaces to terminfo database*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html)